# Jekyll Post Excerpt: How to remove the first paragraph

Tags: jekyll

I know how to use  to define the end of the excerpt, but I'd like to omit the first paragraph of the post as well.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right you just want the first paragraph.

`post.excerpt` gets the first paragraph of your post. An alternative would be to create a variable in your markdown files and call it whenever you want.

e.g.

```
---
layout: post
title: Your title
post_description: A plugin to extend Swiper for easier JW Player integration.
---
```

and call `{{ post.post_description }}` in your lists.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I actually wanted just the 2nd paragraph, and this method works perfectly (just implemented it).  Thanks again, codegaze.

Comment: On the contrary, thank you! You gave me an idea for a post. http://codegaze.github.io/2015/09/07/jekyll-custom-description-for-your-posts/

Comment: The question was about removing the first paragraph but not rendering it instead

Answer (score 11):

Just got into the same issue. I have a separate place for excerpt and below I want post without excerpt (because it was already displayed). What worked for me was:

```
<header>
  {{ page.excerpt }}
</header>

<article>
  {{ content | remove_first:page.excerpt }}
</article>
```

It has to be defined in the same layout you use for posts and posts only.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Here is the docs on `remove_first` filter: http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/remove_first/

Comment: You are my god!